# How to replace column names that include specific string r

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to replace columns that contain "score" string with predefined names.

Here is a simple example dataset and my desired column names to replace.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                  b = c(5,6,7,8,9),
                  c.1_score = c(10,10,2,3,4),
                  a.2_score= c(1,3,5,6,7))

replace.cols <- c("c_score", "a_score")
```

The number of columns changes each trial. So whenever the column name includes `_score`, I would like to replace them with my predefined `replace.cols` names.

The desired col names should be `a b c_score and a_score`.

Any thought?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rename_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
          rename_at(vars(ends_with('score')), ~ replace.cols)

df1
#  a b c_score a_score
#1 1 5      10       1
#2 2 6      10       3
#3 3 7       2       5
#4 4 8       3       6
#5 5 9       4       7
```

---

or with `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
     rename_at(vars(ends_with('score')), ~ str_remove(., '\\.\\d+'))
```

---

Or using `base R` (assuming the column names order is maintained in 'replace.cols')

```
names(df1)[endsWith(names(df1), 'score')] <- replace.cols
```